# Qt, How to catch mouse release events from widgets

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, eventfilter

I've overrode the eventFilter method of the MainWindow of the application

```
  bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){

   if(event->type()== QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
      cout<<"CATCH"<<endl;
   }
   return QObject::eventFilter(obj,event);
  }
```

I can get all events thrown by QWidgets except events arose by QPushButton and Widgets that implement the click event,I mean if I click on the background I can get the release event,if i click
on a QLabel or a QWidget Container i still get the event, but I can't get mouse events from QPushButton, QCalendar, GroupBox etc...

I've tried to promote (I'm using QtCreator) the QPushButton overriding both the methods

```
 void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
 void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
```

But even this does not work because these methods are not called when clicking on the QPushButton.
So I've overrode the filter method of the button and I can catch only graphic events like PaletteChangeEvent or RepaintingEvent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that `QPushButton` has reimplemented eventFilter() for its own internal purposes and handles those events. Therefore they don't reach your event filter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an [EventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) in your buttons and QWidgets to receive the events that are sent to those objects before them.

By doing that you can define a method that receive all the events that are sent to those objects and you can catch the ones you want.

Read this to see an example: [Event Filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Comment: Yes I did it, but i can get only events like qt_repaint, qt_palette_change etc...No mouse events, anyway this happens only with widgets that have been put inside a container like a qPanel, widgets laid down directly on the MainWindow can catch all events type in both the filters, the one installed on the mainWindow and the one installed in the promoted widget